# Strange behavior of Out[]

Tags: front-end, kernel

Let's create two notebooks external.nb and primary.nb.  Then call the external.nb notebook from the primary.nb and investigate values of Out[ ]. The context of the external notebook is not important, however for the demonstration of the strange behavior it should contain number of cells. My external.nb notebook contains 4 cells:

```
a=1;
```

---

```
b=1
```

---

```
c=1
```

---

```
d
```

The primary notebook contains the single cell which calls the external notebook from the primary. If we put both notebooks in the same directory, the  cell is

```
NotebookEvaluate @ FileNameJoin[
  { NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]], "external.nb"}
]
```

Open the *primary.nb* and evaluate the cell which calls the evaluation of the *external.nb*.

The output yields

```
Out[1] = d
```

So it returns output of the last cell of the called notebook.

Now refer to input `%4` of *primary.nb*. I would expect an empty output, since at the moment there is no `%4` out in the primary notebook. However the result is the same `d`.

Asking

```
?? Out[]
```

we see the *primary.nb* knows all `Out[]` values of the *external.nb* notebook. Bug or feature?

Comment: The kernel state (including In/Out values) is not local to notebooks. This is expected.

Comment: That is clear, however why then not to continue the enumeration from the last Out[ ] value the kernel knows in the new notebook? I find this confusing.

Comment: Right, now I see what you mean. `primary.nb` keeps counting up from 1, yet higher input line values are already set in `Out` thanks to `external.nb`. It is indeed strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am guessing that this has to do with the following note in the [`NotebookEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookEvaluate.html) documentation:

> The cells of the notebook are evaluated in a dialog subsession.

Here is an example session demonstrating similar behaviour:

[image]

See [`Dialog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dialog.html) if you are not familiar with it.

Within the dialog, `$Line` keeps getting incremented as usual, and `Out` values are set. But once the dialog finishes, `$Line` is reset to its original value.

This is documented:

> Dialog automatically localizes the values of `$Line`, `$MessageList`, and `$Epilog`.

*Side note:* A dialog is something you would normally encounter not when explicitly entering it, but when interrupting evaluation or when debugging (say, you set the debugger to break on a message/assert). Try e.g. `Do[Pause[1], {i, 30}]`, then interrupt using Alt-`,` (Option-Command-`.` on Mac). Now you can evaluate `i` to check its value, or examine the kernel state in other ways. Exit the dialog using `Return[]`. It is natural that one would not want these evaluations to influence `$Line` once the dialog has finished.

Comment: Since the behavior is documented I conclude this is the intended design feature. I use NotebookEvaluate for package development, because it is much more convenient way to add new definitions and navigate in the many cell notebook than in plain .m file. I think I will try to add Clear[Out] as the last cell in the external.nb.

Comment: @user18792 You can edit an `.m` file as if it were a notebook. You can add section cells and text cells. You can close and open section cells. Try it.